# Accessing properties from within a callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm loading in an image into memory per a solution I found on here, and that's fine, but since it's within a callback, the properties width and height are undefined outside of it.

```
var originalWidth, originalHeight;
$("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        originalWidth = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        originalHeight = this.height; // work for in memory images.
    });
console.log(originalWidth); // undefined obviously since `this` is only accessible within `load`s callback.
```

I thought about maybe putting it within an object like:

```
var originalWidth, originalHeight;
var imgDimensions = {};
$("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        imgDimensions.originalWidth = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        imgDimensions.originalHeight = this.height; // work for in memory images.
    });
console.log(imgDimensions['originalWidth']); // undefined also
```

How can I return those properties from within load()?

Comment: It's not that they are undefined outside of it - they just aren't executed yet. `.load` is binding an event that could occur at any time, so that means code on the next line (`console.log`) does not wait for it to complete. It says "when the image has been loaded, run these lines of code"...but again, it's not blocking the rest of your code like you expect. Anyways, you shouldn't be dependent on `load` - http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ - scroll down to "Caveats of the load event when used with images"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not know nor can you control when the callback will run, you cannot guarantee that the value will be available for your call to log.

Depending on what you want to do with the dimensions, one solution might be to add an onload event handler to your img tag so you can access the values once the item has actually been loaded.

Answer (score 2):

The `console.log` is executing before the load function fires, therefore `originalWidth` is not updated as yet.

Comment: Right. I'm wondering how I can return that value... Do I need to wrap its parent in a closure?

Comment: You use it in the load function.

Comment: You can only know the dimensions once the image has loaded, so you either need to use them in the callback or as I indicate below, use an onload event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `console.log()` from within the callback, you should get a useful result:

```
var originalWidth, originalHeight;
var imgDimensions = {};
$("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        imgDimensions.originalWidth = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        imgDimensions.originalHeight = this.height; // work for in memory images.
        console.log(imgDimensions);
    });
```

As others have explained, the `.load()` callback gets executed at some unspecified time in the future.  There's no point in trying to use the imgDimensions variable until then.